# C++ converting number to words

Tags: c++, string, int

I came across this program in a book to convert a number to words. The initial program converts numbers 1-1000 but then you are asked to modify the program to accept numbers up to 1,000,000. I got it working with numbers up to 20,999 but can't get it to work past that. I've been tinkering with it all day and looked at a lot of program examples online but everyone that I looked at is using techniques that are beyond me as a beginner. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Here is what I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string digitName(int digit);
string teenName(int number);
string tensName(int number);
string intName(int number);


int main()
{
    int input;

    do
    {

    cout << "Please enter a positive integer: ";

    cin >> input;

    cout << "\n" << intName(input) << endl;

    cout << "\n\n" << endl;

    }while (input > 0);

    return 0;
}

string digitName(int digit)
{
    if (digit == 1) return "one";
    if (digit == 2) return "two";
    if (digit == 3) return "three";
    if (digit == 4) return "four";
    if (digit == 5) return "five";
    if (digit == 6) return "six";
    if (digit == 7) return "seven";
    if (digit == 8) return "eight";
    if (digit == 9) return "nine";

    return "";
}

string teenName(int number)
{
    if (number == 10) return "ten";
    if (number == 11) return "eleven";
    if (number == 12) return "twelve";
    if (number == 13) return "thirteen";
    if (number == 14) return "fourteen";
    if (number == 15) return "fifteen";
    if (number == 16) return "sixteen";
    if (number == 17) return "seventeen";
    if (number == 18) return "eighteen";
    if (number == 19) return "nineteen";

    return "";
}

string tensName(int number)
{
    if (number >= 90) return "ninety";
    if (number >= 80) return "eighty";
    if (number >= 70) return "seventy";
    if (number >= 60) return "sixty";
    if (number >= 50) return "fifty";
    if (number >= 40) return "fourty";
    if (number >= 30) return "thirty";
    if (number >= 20) return "twenty";

    return "";
}

string intName(int number)
{
    int part = number;
    string name;

    if (part >= 20000)
    {
        if (part % 10000 == 0)
        {
            name = tensName(part / 1000) + " thousand ";
            part = part % 1000;

        }else
        {
            name = tensName(part / 1000) + " ";
            part = part % 10000;
        }
    }

    if (part >= 10000)
    {
        name = teenName(part / 1000) + " thousand ";
        part = part % 1000;
    }

    if (part >= 1000)
    {
        name = digitName(part / 1000) + " thousand ";
        part = part % 1000;
    }

    if (part >= 100)
    {
        name = name + digitName(part / 100) + " hundred";
        part = part % 100;
    }

    if (part >= 20)
    {
        name = name + " " + tensName(part);
        part = part % 10;

    }else if (part >= 10)
    {
        name = name + " " + teenName(part);
        part = 0;
    }

    if (part > 0)
    {
        name = name + " " + digitName(part);
    }

    return name;
}
```

Comment: Use recursion to avoid duplicating so much code.

Comment: @FengyangWang I understand there are many much more concise ways to code this to get the same result. I've been looking at some of them on here. However I am a beginner and this is the way the book I am using presents it at this point.

Comment: Would it be cheating to read the number into a string and then parse the string?

Comment: @RobertPrévost idk...not sure what that means. I've only been coding for a couple months

Comment: The book be smurfed. It is your duty as a programmer to smart and lazy. If you find a better way to do something, use it.

Comment: @user4581301 I completely agree...I was just trying to figure it out based off of what I know thus far

Comment: Why dont you get the length of the string and then it will give you an idea whether it is hundred thousand or a million. Then you can use `digitname` to start saying `five` hundred thousand...

Comment: @iriejams -- Try this method.  The only thing you need to know how to convert are numbers from 1 to 999.  Anything else is just a matter of putting the word billion, million, and thousand in between each group of three digits.  Right now, you have hardcoded 20000, 10000, etc. -- not necessary.  Just focus on three digit numbers, and you're 90% done.

Comment: Also, to get the number of digits in the number just take `log10(num) + 1` to get the digit count.

Comment: Also, another thing you could do is put those strings in a lookup table instead of endless `if` statements.  For example, `string units [] = {"", "one", "two", "three"..}`, and when you want to print the word "three", it's just `units[3]`.

Answer (score 13):

Two things:  You can save yourself a lot of if typing if you just index into an array.  You can solve the problem more genrally by realizing it repeats after the hundreds case.  thousands, millions, billions, trillions and quadrillions all follow exactly the same pattern, so it can be done recursively.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;

    string digitName(int digit);
    string teenName(int number);
    string tensName(int number);
    string intName(int number);

    vector<string> ones {"","one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
    vector<string> teens {"ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen","sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"};
    vector<string> tens {"", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"};

    string nameForNumber (long number) {
        if (number < 10) {
            return ones[number];
        } else if (number < 20) {
            return teens [number - 10];
        } else if (number < 100) {
            return tens[number / 10] + ((number % 10 != 0) ? " " + nameForNumber(number % 10) : "");
        } else if (number < 1000) {
            return nameForNumber(number / 100) + " hundred" + ((number % 100 != 0) ? " " + nameForNumber(number % 100) : "");
        } else if (number < 1000000) {
            return nameForNumber(number / 1000) + " thousand" + ((number % 1000 != 0) ? " " + nameForNumber(number % 1000) : "");
        } else if (number < 1000000000) {
            return nameForNumber(number / 1000000) + " million" + ((number % 1000000 != 0) ? " " + nameForNumber(number % 1000000) : "");
        } else if (number < 1000000000000) {
            return nameForNumber(number / 1000000000) + " billion" + ((number % 1000000000 != 0) ? " " + nameForNumber(number % 1000000000) : "");
        }
        return "error";
    }

    int main()
    {
        long input;
        do
        {
            cout << "Please enter a positive integer: ";    
            cin >> input;
            cout << "\n" << nameForNumber(input) << endl;
            cout << "\n\n" << endl;
        }while (input > 0);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I've wondering if this approach would work across different languages.  I'm hoping that something like Boost::Locale might already integrate converting a number to a name (and vice-versa).  It SEEMS as if Boost::Locale's as::spellout might solve that problem.