# How I can display the digits of a number with words in c++?

Tags: c++, digits

I have a code and I try to display the digit of a number.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
 main ()
{
    int n, r;
    cout<<"Insert number ";
    cin>>n;

    while(n!=0)

    {
        r=n%10;
        n=n/10;



            switch(r)
            {
                case 0: cout<<"zero ";
                break;
                case 1: cout<<"one ";
                break;
                case 2: cout<<"two ";
                break;
                case 3: cout<<"three ";
                break;
                case 4: cout<<"four ";
                break;
                case 5: cout<<"five ";
                break;
                case 6: cout<<"six ";
                break;
                case 7: cout<<"seven ";
                break;
                case 8: cout<<"eight ";
                break;;
                case 9: cout<<"nine ";
                break;

            }

            cout<<r<<endl;
    }

  return 0;

}
```

the problem is that the output is the number with the digits but it is reversed. for example if I take 423 it will display
3 three
2 two
4 four
but I want them to be reversed
what should I do?

Comment: Read as a string, and iterate from back to front?

Comment: You could use a stack, or use recursion to take advantage of the system stack.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Not AND.  OP is already getting one's place first (reverse of string order) and wants the natural string order.

Comment: Follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40252753/c-converting-number-to-words/40253170). It may help you

Comment: @BenVoigt You're right. Time for a break.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few different ways to go about that.

A simple and straightforward one could be to store the digits in a vector, and use `rbegin()`/`rend()` to go through it in reverse order.

It's not the most efficient way, but it is probably the easiest to follow:

```
int main() {
  // ...
  std::vector<int> digits;
  while(n!=0) {
    r=n%10;
    n=n/10;
    digits.push_back(r);
  }
  for(auto i = digits.rbegin(); i != digits.rend() ++i) {
    switch(*i) {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert int to string then use std::reverse then convert back std::string to int.

second approach is that write simple function that reverse given number:

```
int reverse(int n)
{
 int rn = 0;
 while (n > 0) {
     rn = rn * 10 + n % 10;
     n = n / 10;
 }
 return rn;
}
```

then use result as input to your switch case.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for a beginner to get every digit of an integer is to convert it to a string and then iterate through every character of the string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    
    cout << "Insert a number: ";
    cin >> n;
    
    string str_n = to_string(n);
    int length = str_n.length();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        cout << str_n[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}
```